# Is there an expression that means "the worst of the two combined"?

Tags: idiomatic-language, idiom-request

Is there an expression that means "the worst of the two combined"?

> This is like merging CNN with Fox News while only taking their worst
> sides.

The above doesn't sound very idiomatic. There's a better way of saying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the idiom [worst of both worlds](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/worst+of+both+worlds)

> The worst or least desirable attributes of two different things, situations, or circumstances. The negative version of the more common "best of both worlds."

For your example sentence, you could say something like

> This news channel is terrible, it's a cross between CNN and Fox News with the worst of both worlds.